# LVM input/output error

Tags: filesystems, lvm

When I run the lvdisplay, it showed the following error...

```
/usr/sbin/lvdisplay
    /dev/sdb: read failed after 0 of 2048 at 0: Input/output error
    /dev/sdb1: read failed after 0 of 2048 at 0: Input/output error
    /dev/sdb2: read failed after 0 of 2048 at 0: Input/output error
    /dev/sdb3: read failed after 0 of 2048 at 0: Input/output error
--- Logical volume ---
...
```

I can still see my volumes, when the error is showing everytime, any idea?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What does dmesg output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the drive supports smartctl, you can also get a trivial read on it with `smartctl -H /dev/sdb`.  `smartctl -a /dev/sdb` will give you more information; the SMART attributes data structure is well worth a look.  You can also use `smartctl -t` to run tests on the drive, some of which can be run with the system in normal operation (though they will impact performance); do a `man smartctl` to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the /dev/sdb hard drive is suffering a hardware failure.  Run `dmesg` to check for additional kernel errors.

Run the manufacture's hard drive diagnostic software against the disk to determine actual failure.

Comment: I am using Seagate HD, what tools I can used to check without reboot/shutdown the machine?

Thanks.

Comment: You could attempt a `fsck` if you can unmount the filesystem but if your disk is spitting I/O errors in `dmesg`, chances are any remediation will require reboot/shutdown unless you can hot swap your disks.